# Why Non-parallel but full case statement uses ROM not the MUX?

Tags: verilog, cases

as far as I know, when the items in case are not parallel

it would compose a priority routing network not the multiplexing network.

In other words, it should uses multiple 2-to-1 MUXs to represent priority in between the case items.

For example, below code has non-parallel case items **3'b11** and **3'b1??**.

```
module non_parallel_but_full_case
(
  input wire [2:0] s,
  output reg y
);
  always @*
  //below case is not parallel but full case
    casez (s)
      3'b111: y = 1'b1;
      3'b1??: y = 1'b0;
      default: y = 1'b1;
    endcase
endmodule
```

Therefore, I've expected the synthesized circuit may have MUXs not the ROM.

However, when I tested the code in the vivado and its RTL description shows ROM not the MUX.

[image: RTL descrption of the non-parallel but full case]

Why the non-parallel case uses the ROM instead of the MUXs?

=====================================================
Added question.

```
module decoder_2_4_if (
  input wire [1:0] a,
  input wire en,
  output reg [3:0] y
);

  always @*
    if (en == 1'b0)
      y = 4'b0000;
    else if (a == 2'b00)
      y = 4'b0001;
    else if (a == 2'b01)
      y = 4'b0010;
    else if (a == 2'b10)
      y = 4'b0100;
    else
      y = 4'b1000;
endmodule
```

The above code generates the multiple cascaded 2-to-1 MUXs.

However, the same logic implemented by the case statement uses the ROM.

```
module decoder_2_4_case (
  input wire [1:0] a,
  input wire en,
  output reg [3:0] y
);

  always @*
  case ({en,a})
    3'b000, 3'b001, 3'b010, 3'b011: y = 4'b000;
    3'b100: y = 4'b0001;
    3'b101: y = 4'b0010;
    3'b110: y = 4'b0100;
    3'b111: y = 4'b1000;
  endcase
endmodule
```

In two examples, the result can be statically determined, and it would mean that two modules could be implemented by the ROM.

Then why it generates the different schematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the non-parallel case uses the ROM instead of the MUXs?

Because that's the right thing to do here!

You feed in values, you get out static values. Classical case for ROM, or in the case of FPGAs, an elemental LUT.

A mux would need the same LUT to mux the right static signals. So, the mux solution for this static case is less efficient than just ROM.

> In other words, it should uses multiple 2-to-1 MUXs to represent priority in between the case items.

I don't see a reason why.

Regarding your edit:

You implicitly define a priority order when doing your `else if` thing, so here, the synthesizer has no choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still having a hard time to understand it. When I use the if statement, it utilizes multiple cascaded 2-to-1 MUXs, but when I use the non-parallel case, it uses the ROM. If my understanding is correct, a ROM stores the precalculated values and it is much faster than the composing the circuits like and or nand etc. So is that a reason why the ROM is used instead of the cascaded 2-to-1 MUXs in the above example?

Comment: By the way, out of curiosity, if case statements are converted to the ROM to be efficient, is that a reason why the verilog doesn't allow the >, < operators in the case items?

Comment: you're mixing things up. It's not used because it's faster, it's used because any other implementation would include the same LUT component.  and: `<` is an arithmetic operator. you need to implement arithmetic logic to have it. So, you tell me how the combinatorial way to compare two 64bit variables looks like, and then you see why we don't do that.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you, as a dummy in FPGA area, I cannot understand your answer completely. What do you mean by any other implementation would include the same LUT component? And I just added one more related question. Could you please give me a little more help? I appreciate your help :D

Comment: So, how would you implement this using a MUX? You would have a) "constants" that you b) select with a mux setting. That mux setting is also a Look-Up Table (LUT), and those constants are often also implemented using LUTs. So, your MUX solution simply /contains/ a LUT, and hence, you can also directly use a LUT without having *any* disadvantage.

Comment: Aha.. the MUX will be synthesized using the LUT and the result would be the same whether I use the if statement or case statement above right? I think the RTL schematic confused me because it shows the MUX when the if statement is used and it shows the ROM when the case statement is used.

Comment: Marcus is spot on, @JaeHyukLee. Remember that every bit of combinatorial circuitry in an FPGA is implemented by ROMs, effectively (actually by configured RAM-based LUTs that won't change during operation). There are no muxes or AND/OR/NOT/XOR gates - just LUTs. There's no difference in functional behaviour between a combinatorial circuit full of AND/OR/NOT/XOR gates and a ROM with enough address inputs and data outputs.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for being kind to answer my poor question :D. I thought that the RTL description is the real synthesized circuit in the FPGA, but it didn't! However, I have one remaining question. From the book FPGA titled "prototyping by Verilog Examples" it says if statement constructs priority routing networks, and case constructs multiplexing routing network. If all combinational circuitry in an FPGA is implemented with the ROM what does it mean by the multiplexing network and priority routing network?

Comment: @TonyM and this book says 
"In  general,  the priority  routing  network  is more effective when  a preference  is given under  certain conditions,  such as for a priority  encoder,  and the multiplexing  network  is more effective for a truth  table or function table-based  description, such as for a binary decoder." 
I cannot understand above sentence if all circuits are implemented by making use of the ROMs in any cases.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee, please go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70402/discussion-between-jaehyuk-lee-and-tonym